# Link custom library to existing program in C++

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

I've written a simple memory management program (which overwrites malloc, realloc...) in C++ and created shared library (.so file) from it. Now I want to test it with an existing program, for this I have chosen CenterIM5 and compiled it. How do I link the library to CenterIM5, so that it uses my functions?

Comment: do you work with cmake or make?

Comment: I'm calling make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to link to your library at runtime by running it with `LD_PRELOAD` set:

```
LD_PRELOAD=path/to/so ./app args
```

In this case you don't need to rebuild anything.

Comment: With what would i replace ./app? Just centerim doesn't work.

Comment: Well, that depends on the app you want to run (I don't know much about Centerim). Basically you take command line and prepend `LD_PRELOAD=...` to it.